# How to set table name as variable and insert variables into sqlite table in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I created three tables and i want to create a function that will populate the tables with variable values depending of one of the variables values, as they are updated by another function.

```
 c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unu (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, item1 TEXT, item2 INT)')
 c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doi (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, item1 TEXT, item2 INT)')
 c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trei (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, item1 TEXT, item2 INT)')

update_tables()

def tablepopulate(table):
    query = 'SELECT item2 FROM {} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'.format(table) 
    insert ='INSERT INTO {} (item1,item2) VALUES (?,?)'.format(table)
    c.execute(query)
    xy=c.fetchone()
    if xy == None :
        c.execute(insert,(item1, item2))
    elif xy[1] == 0
        c.execute(insert,(item1, item2))

try:
    tablepopulate("unu")
except:
    try:
       tablepopulate("doi")
    except:
       try:
          tablepopulate("trei")
       except:
          print("all tables are populated")
```

This code will not give me any errors but it will not populate the tables

Comment: It doesn't show you any errors because you explicitly hide them. Remove all those try/excepts and show what the actual errors are.

Comment: There's a number of things here. It's possible that you need to `conn.commit()` the changes after creating the tables. But also, `'SELECT item2 FROM {}ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'.format(table)` would need a space after `{}` and then `'INSERT INTO {}(?,?)VALUES(item1,item2)'.format(table)` is back-to-front and probably should be `'INSERT INTO {} (item1, item2) VALUES (?,?)'.format(table)`. Then again, `item1` and `item2` are not defined in `tablepopulate()`.

Comment: careful about typos : `CREATE TABLE IF NOT  EXIST(S)` , `if xy =(=) None :`

Comment: @roganjosh you are right about my code in the question, why i did not get any errors was because in my actual code i did have the syntax right, and you are right, i simply forgot to commit, i will update my question with the correct syntax, if you post an answer i will accept it

Comment: If your syntax is correct in your actual code then you did a very poor job of representing it in the question because there are multiple things that will definitely throw errors. `conn.commit()` will not fix the other errors I mentioned, and even fixing those will not guarantee that it runs as expected.

Comment: @PRMoureu you are right i will update my code

Comment: @roganjosh the code does work and as i said i will accept an answer if you post is even if it is so trivial as it may benefit other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit the changes after you make them. So something like `conn.commit()`, where `conn` is whatever you called your database connection.

Separately, `if xy == None :` is not best practice; if you had instead done `c.fetchall()` then you would get an empty list back. You can cover both bases by using `if not xy:`, which will catch both falsey cases.

`item1` and `item2` are not defined that I can see. That will throw an error in `tablepopulate()` so you perhaps want to pass them as arguments.

Finally, it's not a great idea to use the nested `try`/`except` structure that you have. For one, you're using the blanket `except` rather than catching a specific error but also, the `print("all tables are populated")` almost certainly isn't true if you get down to that level.

Answer (score -2):

Regardless of how you solve the problem

this line:

```
insert ='INSERT INTO {}(?,?)VALUES(item1,item2)'.format(table)
```

should look like:

```
insert ='INSERT INTO {0} VALUES("{1}","{2}")'.format(tab,item1,item2)
```

Comment: No, it should not.

Comment: Well, no, because the OP was half way there to building the query correctly. Now you just `format` the parameters into the string.